# jQuery li id in absolute

Tags: jquery

after fetch list from server and append to `<ul>` i cant get `<li>` id in absolute

**FETCH FROM SERVER :**

```
$('#listCategories').empty();
$.post("model/controller.php",
    { 
        postaction:'getCategoryList'
    },
    function(data){
        categoryList = data.message ;
        console.log( categoryList );
        $.each( categoryList , function( i , item ){
            alert( "moveTo_"+categoryList[i].id );
            $('#listCategories').append("<li class='has-sub' id = 'moveTo_"+categoryList[i].id+"'><a href='javascript:void(0);'><span>"+categoryList[i].title+"</span></a></li>");
        });

},'json');
```

**CLICK ON LIST :**

```
$('[id^="moveTo_"]').on('click',function(){
    alert( $(this).attr('id') );
   $('[id^="cssmenu"]').hide(); // HIDE ALL SUBMENUS
   category_id = $(this).attr('id').split(/\_/)[1] ;
   $.post('model/controller.php', 
            {
                topic_id     : public_iId_topics  ,
                category_id  : category_id ,
                postaction   : 'move_current_post_category'
            }, 
      function(data){
            if (data.success){
                public_oTable.dataTable().fnReloadAjax();
                public_oTable.dataTable().fnDraw();
                animate_notify(data.message     , 2000 , '.content','',410,437);
            }
            else
                animate_notify(data.message     , 2000 , '.content','',410,437);
    },'json');
    return false;       
});
```

**HTML :**

```
   <li class='last'><a href='javascript:void(0);'><span><?php _tr( 'move_topic' ); ?></span></a>
       <ul id='listCategories'></ul>
   </li>
```

fetch and append list of category is ok and i dont have problem to insert that, but after click on lists i cant get event and `.click()` not working.

Comment: Ooo it's my favorite daily question.. answer is event delegation..

Comment: @Zenith please voteUP ;)

Comment: @mahdipishguy you should go through some already given answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the delegated `li`'s `on`, rather than binding to the individual elements. Update your binding as follows:

```
$('li').on('click', '[id^="moveTo_"]', function(e) {
    // Your function here...
});
```

Comment: Why not something like `$("li").on('click', '[id^="moveTo_"]', function(e) {`? Won't it have better performance?

Comment: Yeah, it would, you're right. However, I didn't look at the markup the OP posted (lazy, I know), and so wasn't aware that his IDs only ever applied to `li` items. I'll update the answer.